# Impersonation of user within PowerShell triggered from C# code

Tags: c#, powershell, impersonation

I am using c# to invoke a powershell script, which has content inside it which should run as a specific user.

1. I have C# implementation of impersonation completed logic mentioned as per with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998258.aspx#pagguidelines0001_impersonationdelegation
2. I have trouble with the implementation code which is the following:

   ```
   PSInvocationSettings settings = new PSInvocationSettings();
   settings.FlowImpersonationPolicy = true;
   //settings.ErrorActionPreference = ActionPreference.Stop;
   IEnumerable input = null;
   resultsfromps = ps.Invoke<PSObject>(input, settings);
   ```

I did the lines for `PSInvocationSettings`, `flowimpersonationPolicy`, `ps.Invoke` using msdn help, but i'm not sure what I should set value to the `input` variable.

So the code sorta works, it's creating a powershell invocation, but appears the script inside runs - but with empty username and empty password.

ANy help on doing this appreciated !

Comment: Some time ago, I faced a similar task. What me helped me a lot was this article: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q306158#4 It it more or less copy & paste to get this code working.

Comment: Impersonation doesn't get you a password.  Does your PowerShell commandlet require one?

Comment: Rob : That code solves impersonation from a C# angle. But that's doesnt forward the user credential i need for the powershell script. (I still see it running on the app account, though i had the invoke under Impersonation context block (before Undo)

Bmm60 : Powershell script requires an admin privilege as by default my app runs the script with lower user. As mentioned i used the code in the link, but it doesnt impersonate the context of script inside PS.Invoke()

Comment: What do you mean by "but with empty username and empty password" then?

Comment: yet another broken Microsoft support link.... support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q306158#4